# Modify image lightness(hsl) using rmagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, rmagick

I need to programmatically modify the lightness factor (HSL) of an image in my rails app during uploading. I am currently using rmagick/imagemagick for other image manipulations. But, can't figure out how to modify the lightness.

The closest I found was:

img.modulate(brightness, hue, saturation),

but this does not modify the lightness factor. Can somebody please help me on how do I get this working?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Varun

Comment: [contrast method will help](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image1.html#contrast)

Comment: Thanks Eugene for the reply. But the contrast method provides a static (true/false). It does not provide a scale as to how much contrast we want to apply on the image. Moreover, 'contrast' and  'lightness' are giving me different results on Photoshop :(

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question properly, but this is how I use ImageMagick to convert an image to HSL colourspace and then modify the brightness - i.e. stretch the contrast of the Lightness channel:

```
convert image.jpg -colorspace HSL -channel L -contrast-stretch 5%,5% +channel output.jpg
```